# In TeXnicCenter, click on error in output window does not show where error occured

Tags: texniccenter

I recently downloaded the most recent version of TeXnicCenter.  In the past when I built my project, I could click on an error or warning message in the output window and a green arrow would appear to the left of the line number in the source code window where the error occurred.  This doesn't work any more.

Could someone please explain to me how to set this up?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I removed the thanks (the change will show up in a minute). This is just the style here. If someone helps you, up vote their answer to thank them.

Comment: By "the most recent", do you mean the alpha version of TXC 2.0? (Just to clarify, I don't think I can help you, as I don't use TXC myself.)

Comment: Could it be that this only works if you are within a texniccenter-project?

Comment: Not a green arrow but a red arrow. It should work without manual settings.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this is neither the case with TeXnicCenter 1.0 Stable Release Candidate 1 (dated 2008-12-07):

[image]

nor with the most recent TeXnicCenter 2.0 Alpha 3 (build 1118):

[image]

where both identify the error correctly without any modifications. The [most recent bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2966477&group_id=36323&atid=479426) showing similar problems date back to 2010-03-09 and references 1.75 Beta, while the latest Alpha release/build is dated 2010-05-30.

I suggest [updating to the latest Alpha release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texniccenter/files/TeXnicCenter%20Alpha/TXCSetup_2Alpha3.exe/download), or reverting back to the [stable release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texniccenter/files/TeXnicCenter/1.0%20Stable%20RC1/TXCSetup_1StableRC1.exe/download).

Comment: I'm using 1.0 Stable release.  I notice when I just create a small document like you did above and build it, the arrow shows up.  I'll try to investigate it further starting with this observation and if I can't get it to work, I'll do as you say and re-load the software

Comment: Ok, I got it:  apparently you can't name a file with two words like "my project".  The file I was having the problems with the arrow was named that way.  When I save it with a single continuous name liek "myproject" the arrow shows up.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm struggling a bit with all this.  I have resolved the problem though.  Not sure it's the double-word thing.  Look like rather, I allowed such a build-up of errors in my original file (more than 80 or so), that somehow it caused the arrow mechanism to stop working.  So I created a brand new project and cut-and paste from the old file and now have the arrow working and with zero errors reporting.  I'll work towards addressing the errors as they occur now.

Comment: @Jack: Your last observation is an important one. Perhaps, you could search on the [TeXnicCenter bug report list](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=36323&atid=416430) and see if there is anything that matches your experience. If not, report it so that the developers can look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before

just check the path of the file and you should find some spaces in it such as `file 1`  just remove this space to be `file1` then it should work